# How do I format code selection and maintain leading trivia with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to  format the code that I modified with roslyn.
I am modifying code inside a method.
I don't want to reformat the entire file.
The original formatting looks the following:

```
MyNamespace
{
    class CodeBasicTests
    {
        int OperationOrder_0()
        {
            int a = 20;
            int b = 10;
            int sum = a + b;
            return (int) sum;
        }
    }
}
```

After I format the body of the method, it gets aligned to the border, not to the method signature.

```
MyNamespace
{
    class CodeBasicTests
    {
int OperationOrder_0()
{
    int a = 20;
    int b = 10;
    int c = 30; //new instruction
    int sum = a + b + c;
    return (int) sum;
}
     }
}
```

I have tried the following inside the method visitor (CSharpSyntaxRewriter):

```
MethodDeclarationSyntax method = visited method node;
updatedMethod = method.ReplaceNode(method.Body, newBody);
updatedMethod = updatedMethod.NormalizeWhitespace().WithTriviaFrom(method);
return updatedMethod;
```

or selecting only the method body

```
newBody = (BlockSyntax) Formatter.Format(oldBody, texts, VisualStudioSolutionHandler.workspace);
```

I have tried also to work with the text spans of the formatter, but I don't manage to make it work at at all.

I don't want/know to write a visitor to insert a right tab to every element in the newBody because the statements that I insert are much more complex, and I would like to use the autoformatting feature for the updated method only.

I don't know hot to keep the original method indentation.

Comment: Can you give some information as to how the rest of your code looks? It will look at the surrounding nodes to determine at what level your method has to be indented which might throw it off.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel thanks for the feedback. I hope my problem is clearer now.

Comment: Could you instead add an annotation to your method (`method.WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation)`) and use the `Formatter.Format(node, Formatter.Annotation)` overload? What does that yield you?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the trivia with the current trivia list with the new trivia inserted in place.

Here's an example of an extension method I created to add newlines to certain annotated nodes.

```
public static TNode AddNewlineToAnnotated<TNode>(this TNode node, string annotationKind)
    where TNode : CSharpSyntaxNode =>
    node.ReplaceNodes(node.GetAnnotatedNodes(annotationKind), (_, n) =>
        n.WithLeadingTrivia(n.GetLeadingTrivia()
            .Insert(0, SyntaxTree.ElasticEndOfLine(Environment.NewLine))
        )
    );
```

Getting the leading trivia gives you a `SyntaxTriviaList` and you can `Add()`, `Insert()` or otherwise modify the trivia list to give you a new trivia list.